# Changing variables after a certain amount of time

Tags: python, variables, time, pygame

im making a pygame and im trying to make the game progessively harder by speeding up thee enemies every ten seconds

here is the method Im trying:

```
def time_pass(self):
    #timer for main game play
    self.time_passed = time.clock()
    if self.time_passed == (self.start_time + 10):
        self.str_spd1 += 2
        self.str_spd2 += 2
        self.str_spd3 += 2
```

`self.star_time` is the time the gameplay started and `self.time_passed` is the time in seconds since the program started

so if the game has been runnig for ten seconds the speed should increase by 2 but its only happening when the time is exactly 10 then it goes back

if i use `>` instead `==` the game like crashes cause the stars accelarate

so i need a way to make it so that every ten seconds the speed of the stars will increase by 2

Comment: Barney Govan's answer tells you how to do what you're asking… but it's a very bad idea. There's no guarantee that any clock tick will exactly match 10 seconds after program start (or 20, or 30). For example, one may be 9.953 seconds after start, and the next 10.004 seconds after.

Comment: yes i should have stated my question clearer

Comment: Also, [`time.clock()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.clock) is almost never what you want in the first place. It's processor time on Unix, wall clock time on Windows, and unspecified on other platforms.

Comment: @abarnert then what should i use???

Comment: If you don't need sub-second precision, and don't want to deal with system clock changes, [`time.time`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time) is the simplest solution. If you need either of the above… ask a new question, because it's way too complicated to put into a comment. But the short version is, if you're using PyGame, you can use its `pygame.time` module.

Comment: For timing use [pygame.time.get_ticks()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks) to get time elapsed in **milliseconds**

Comment: @monkey Oh!! that will work! i just need to tweak it a bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python 2.x does not have a reliable way to count seconds since launch.

`time.clock()` is very wrong—on any platform other than Windows, it's counting CPU time instead of wall clock time.

`time.time()` is closer, in that it's wall clock on every platform. It's not guaranteed to have sub-second precision, but when you're only checking every 10 seconds, that's no problem. What *is* a problem is that it doesn't handle changes to the system clock very nicely. For example, if you set your clock ahead an hour, the timer won't fire for 3610 seconds instead of just 10.

Fortunately, `PyGame` has its [`pygame.time`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html) module, with features designed specifically to deal with cases like this.

The easiest thing to do is to just use `pygame.game.set_timer`. Instead of checking the time every frame or every idle tick or whatever, just add an event handler and ask PyGame to fire that event every 10 seconds.

If that isn't appropriate, `pygame.time.get_ticks` gives you the number of milliseconds of wall clock time since the game started, which is probably what you'd want to use with Elazar's code.

But it's worth reading the linked page, and some of the examples, before deciding what you want to do.

Comment: i tried this and got very confused but ill try again thanks so much for the help ! @abarnert

Comment: @ChristianCareaga: Look at the examples linked from each function. If you try a solution and get stuck, write a new question asking for help.

Answer (score 2):

in `__init__`:   `self.i = 0`

```
if self.time_passed >= (self.start_time + 10 * self.i):
    self.i += 1
    ...
```

Comment: ok i didnt see the top part ohh i should have thought of that genuis!

Comment: I've added it. @Barney Govan's version is better, if you do it each clock tick.

Comment: This isn't what the OP asked for, but it's close to what he _should_ have asked for. The only problem is that, on most non-Windows systems, it will fire every 10 seconds of CPU time, not every 10 seconds of wall clock time, because `time.clock()` is not wall clock time.

Comment: This one is safer, and more likely to work -- it handles non-integer seconds and irregular method calls.

Comment: @abarnert so what is your suggestion?

Comment: @Elazar: [`pygame.time`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html) instead of the stdlib.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the modulus operator:

```
if (self.time_passed - self.start_time) % 10 == 0:
    ...
```

Comment: It's better than my suggestion, or wrong. it depends on how time.clock() is implemented.

Comment: @Elazar: No, this won't work on most platforms. It is, however, exactly what the OP asked for.

Comment: Yes -- this assumes we get to call every second, and also that time.clock() is integer seconds.

Comment: … neither of which is true on either Windows or Unix.

Comment: yeah becuase this way it has to be exactly 10 not 9.678 or 10.5 but very good answer